# Showing JSON data in listview

Tags: javascript, android, json

```
function onLoad(){

    document.title = App.Properties.__caption;  
    document.getElementById('blockName').innerText = App.Properties.__caption;
    getAllRecords();
};

function getAllRecords(){

    //Get all the records available in the excel building block

    window.App.Core.getRecords(function(products){

        var product ='';

        for(var i = 0; i < products.length; i++){

            //Get the current record

            product = products[i];

            document.write(JSON.stringify(product, ['name', 'description','imageid', 'price', 'qty', 'shop']));
        }
    });
};
```

Comment: What is your problem..?

Comment: it only show the raw data .